# Nexus 3 Query builder how to retrieve artefacts in descending order

Tags: groovy, nexus, nexus3

Is there a way we can retrieve artefacts in date descending order?

I currently have below script here as an example:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args)
assert request.groupId: 'groupId parameter is required'
assert request.repoName: 'repoName parameter is required'
assert request.startDate: 'startDate parameter is required, format: yyyy-mm-dd'

log.info("Gathering Asset list for repository: ${request.repoName} as of startDate: ${request.startDate}")

def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(request.repoName)
StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)
def tx = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()

tx.begin()

Iterable<Asset> assets = tx.
    findAssets(Query.builder()
      .where('group = ').param(request.groupId)
      .and('last_updated > ').param(request.startDate)
      .build(), [repo])
def urls = assets.collect { "/repository/${repo.name}/${it.name()}" }

tx.commit()

def result = JsonOutput.toJson([
    assets  : urls,
    since   : request.startDate,
    repoName: request.repoName
])
return result
```

with:

```
Query.builder()
          .where('group = ').param(request.groupId)
          .and('last_updated > ').param(request.startDate)
          .build()
def urls = assets.collect { "/repository/${repo.name}/${it.name()}" }
```

Is there a way we can change above script to retrieve things in date descending order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a suffix.

```
Query.builder()
          .where('group = ').param(request.groupId)
          .and('last_updated > ').param(request.startDate)
          .suffix('order by last_updated desc')
          .build()
def urls = assets.collect { "/repository/${repo.name}/${it.name()}" }
```

Nexus is using OrientDB behind the scene. You can find query examples here:
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-SQL.html