# Numeric string sorting using Iterable<Component> in groovy

Tags: groovy, nexus, artifact

I want to sort version from `Iterable<Component> components`. Нow when i print in the console it shows me the following result:

```
artifact 1.0.1
artifact 1.0.10
artifact 1.0.11
artifact 1.0.12
artifcat 1.0.2
artifcat 1.0.3
artifcat 1.0.4
```

This is my code

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

def repoName = "artifact"

log.info("delete components for repository: " + repoName)


def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repoName)
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get()
try {
tx.begin()
    Iterable<Component> components = tx.findComponents(Query.builder()
      .where('version < ').param('1.1.0')
      .build(), [repo])
    tx.commit()
    
    for(Component c : components) {
        log.info("Name " + c.name() + " Version" + c.version())
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Transaction failed {}", e.toString())
    tx.rollback()
} finally {
    tx.close()
}
```

Comment: There are some scenarios that aren't represented in your sample output to know for sure what the requirement is.  Does `components.sort {it.version()}` yield the desired order?

Comment: Your title says *Numeric string sorting* but your output shows `1.0.2` coming _after_ `1.0.11` which suggests maybe your requirement is alpha sorting.

Comment: components.sort {it.version()} from where does it come this "it"

Comment: "where does it come this it" - In Groovy, if a closure does not declare an argument list, the closure will accept 1 optional argument, named `it`.  `{ it.version() }`, `{ it -> it.version() }` and `{ comp -> comp.version() }` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: I tried it like this before components = components.sort { it.size() }, but it gave me a error, but I don't remember it at the moment. I guess it gave me the error because I'm a using size, not a version

Comment: "components = components.sort { it.size() }" - That is valid Groovy and will not throw an error at runtime if all of the elements in `components` has a method on it named `size` that accepts no arguments.

Comment: I thought you wanted to sort on version so I suggested `components = components.sort { it.version() }`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it tomorrow, if there's anything I'll write, thank you very much

Comment: I know it lacks some documentation on sonatype side (and it might actually not work since I could not test) but.... did you try to sort the components beforehand right from the orientdb result ? => `.suffix('orderby version')` (to be added right before the query `.build()`). Some references [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820194/9401096)

Answer (score 1):

Some simple sorting by version can be done as follows:

```
def components = []
'''\
artifact 1.2.1
artifact 1.0.1
artifact 1.0.10
artifact 2.0.10
artifact 1.0.11
artifact 1.0.12
artifact 1.4.12
artifcat 1.0.2
artifcat 1.0.3
artifcat 1.0.4'''.splitEachLine( ' ' ){ name, version ->
  components << [ name:name, version:version ]
}

// augment each component with numeric represenation of version
components.each{
  it.versionNumeric = it.version.split( /\./ )*.toInteger().reverse().withIndex().sum{ num, pow -> 100.power( pow ) * num }
}

components.sort{ it.versionNumeric }*.version.join '\n'
```

prints

```
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.0.10
1.0.11
1.0.12
1.2.1
1.4.12
2.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
def components = '''\
artifact 1.2.1
artifact 1.0.1
artifact 1.0.10
artifact 2.0.10
artifact 10.2
artifact 1.0.11
artifact 1.0.12
artifact 1.4.12
artifcat 1.0.2
artifcat 1.0.3
artifcat 1.0.4
artifact 1.0.4.2'''.readLines()*.tokenize(' ').collect { name, version ->
  [name: name, version: version]
}

def sorted = components.sort { a, b ->
  def f = { it.version.tokenize('.')*.toInteger() }
  [f(a), f(b)].transpose().findResult { ai, bi -> 
    ai <=> bi ?: null 
  } ?: a.version <=> b.version
}

sorted.each { c -> 
    println c.version
}
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.0.4.2
1.0.10
1.0.11
1.0.12
1.2.1
1.4.12
2.0.10
10.2
```

Note that this solution also (at least more or less) handles versions with differing numbers of elements such as `10.2` and `1.0.4.2`.